# How to add css style to GtkBox in Gtk+ 3

Tags: python, css, ubuntu, gtk

I wanna to create an Ubuntu application with GTK+ 3 and Python, but i'm new to GTK.

i have a css style of gtkbox in below image, but how can i add this style to my GtkBox/GtkVBox object to be like in image.
[image of my concept](http://ubuntuone.com/1Gf1kSkTz0x9PWBDMXbVbm)

**NOTE:** This image has been created by photoshop.

Comment: Which style, what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Why css style don't work on GtkButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983385/why-css-style-dont-work-on-gtkbutton)

```
cssProvider = Gtk.CssProvider()
cssProvider.load_from_path('style.css')
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
styleContext = Gtk.StyleContext()
styleContext.add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssProvider,
Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER) # With the others GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY values get the same result.
```