# Change color of HBOX or VBOX in GTK

Tags: c, gtk

I know how to change color background of GtkButton, which some code:

```
GdkColor color;
color.red = 65535;
color.green = 0;
color.blue = 0;
gtk_widget_modify_bg(button,GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&color);
```

But when I apply it to GtkHBox, It don't effect. I don't change background color for any Widget except GtkButton. Anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **GtkBox** and it children classes don't draw a background, so no matters what you tell the it background color it, it won't do anything.

You need, if you want to change the background color, to search which widget is drawing the background and change the color of that one, with `gtk_widget_override_background_color`

Widgets that render a background are, for instance:

- GtkButton
- [GtkFrame](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFrame.html)
- GtkInfoBar
- [GtkEventBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEventBox.html)

Answer (score 0):

I answered that question in: [How to add css style to GtkBox in Gtk+ 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675699/how-to-add-css-style-to-gtkbox-in-gtk-3/17693397#17693397)

Bsaically: don't use the `gtk_widget_modify_bg` or `_fg` functions, use a `GtkStyleProvider`

Answer (score 0):

yes, i have a answer for me. I use EventBox for Draw Background, it is true useful. I just add parent for HBox or VBox, and set background for HBox, it's done!